# Combine executables from separate Docker images?

Tags: docker

Let's say I need `A.exe` and `B.exe` installed in my final [`node`](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) image by runtime. Both `A.exe` and `B.exe` happen to be available on Docker Hub, but they're from separate images. Does Docker have a way to somehow make both executables from different images available in my final image?

I don't think Docker's multi-stage build is relevant as it only simplifies passing **artefacts** that we want available on the next image. Whereas in my case, I need the whole runtime environment from previous images to be available. I have the option to [`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) shell commands to manually install these dependencies but is this really the only way?

Comment: There's no way to merge images, and in the general case it can be hard to copy an executable from one image to another (bringing along its supporting data files, shared library dependencies, ...).  Usually the best approach is to use underlying Linux distribution's package manager (`apt-get` or `apk`) to install the dependencies in your Dockerfile.

Comment: I see. I suppose there's no other way than to manually `apt-get`/`apk`-ing these dependencies and wire them up myself. If that's the case, you might want to put your comment as answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [multistage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/), since you could declare a.exe/b.exe together with the required runtime to be the required artefacts.

But I agree it could be easier if you install the runtime from packages and just copy the application.

Comment: But to pass `A.exe` and `B.exe` as artefacts in a multi-stage build would mean I have to know what files to copy from where in their images' file systems, right? (Such as data files and shared lib deps that David Maze commented about.) This means doing multi-stage build for this task is impractical if not impossible. It would indeed be great if Docker made it easier to "compose" images in the way I needed (as opposed to docker-composing containers), but I suppose they couldn't for technical reasons. Thanks for your Answer Hiran!

Comment: Why do you need them in one image anyway? Should not usually every image run one process only?

Answer (score 0):

If you feel sure enough about what you need, you could [export](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/) image A and image B as tar balls.

Now comes the tricky part: merging the two filesystem structures
Extract both archives such that you have one target filesystem structure and wrap that up into a tar ball again.

So it is not impossible to get the files - but you need to know exactly what you are doing.

Finally [import](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/) that tar ball into a docker image.

Answer (score 0):

One option to get a combined image is not to merge two images but maybe merge two dockerfiles. This may need a review once in a while but might even change less often than the images themselves.